# Availability Test Summary widget showing results for each individual test inside 1 single Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-dashboard

I have 1 single Application Insights which I strictly use to monitor the health of some external sites I'm dependent on, by using the Availability blade and setting up Standard Test (URL ping test) like seen below where I have 3 Standard tests:

[image]

I want to have 3 different "Application Tests Summary" Dashboard widgets each showing the availability and the total successful test and total failed tests numbers for a **single** Standard Test. Below screenshots shows what I have if I just add the widget and point it to my App Insights, then it will take the results from ALL 3 Standard Tests and you cannot see which of my 3 HealtCheck-Site-0x failed on this widget. You have to click on the widget to take you into the App Insights then you can see the results as in the first screenshot.

[image]

So is it possible to somehow create a similar widget that shows results of availability, total successful and total failed tests for 1 single Standard Test? Then I would be able to create 3 of the widgets on my Dashboard, each showing its own results from a Standard Health Check test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most App Insights pins respect filters.
What you can do is to apply "test name" filter before pinning:
[image]

Here is how it looks on the dashboard:
[image]

You can add any filters or update the time range and it should also work.

Comment: Brilliant. Thx so much. I gave up on this but now I can see it is doable. I spent a little time digging for the Pin icon. It only appears if you choose Scatter Plot.